# Can a monk use the Stunning Strike feature on an opportunity attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, monk, opportunity-attack

The description of the monk's [Stunning Strike](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/monk#StunningStrike-235) class feature states:

> When you hit with a melee weapon attack, you can spend 1 ki point to make the target stunned until the end of your next turn if it fails a CON saving throw.

An [opportunity attack](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#OpportunityAttacks) allows you to:

> use your reaction to make one melee attack against the provoking creature.

Does an opportunity attack made with a melee weapon allow a monk to use Stunning Strike if the attack hits?

Comment: Note that it doesn't have to be a melee weapon; unarmed strikes are melee weapon attacks, despite not using weapons, so Stunning Strike can be used on unarmed strikes. See these Q&As: [Can the monk's Stunning Strike feature be used with Martial Arts?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/46051/33569), [Is an Unarmed Strike considered a Weapon attack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/58158/33569)

Comment: Note that unlike a _Stunning Strike_ on your own turn, one accomplished on another turn (presumably that of the creature you are stunning), may have a greater or lesser strategic value in that it may last an entire round or much less, and may open the creature up to advantaged attacks from many allies or just you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Yes, this works.

The only conditions for using Stunning Strike are:

- you hit
- with a melee weapon attack
- You spend 1 ki point

So when you make an opportunity attack, and hit with a melee weapon attack, you can spend 1 ki point to use stunning strike.